# Create an array of selected radio button values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have few radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" value="####.###/resources/videos/7.mp4">
<input type="radio" value="####.###/resources/videos/8.mp4">
<input type="radio" value="####.###/resources/videos/9.mp4">
```

How can I make an array containing the selected values like following:

```
var videos = ["./resources/videos/7.mp4", 
             "./resources/videos/1.mp4", 
             "./resources/videos/2.mp4", 
             "./resources/videos/3.mp4"];
```

Comment: Firstly, you could use `map()` to achieve this. Secondly, you cannot deselect any of those radio buttons. It seems like checkboxes would be a much better idea in this use case.

Comment: How should the inputs work? Should you be able to deselect an input by clicking it again? Should selecting an input deselect all other inputs?

Comment: Out of all radio buttons in a group, you can have only one value out of them. So if you are expecting an array of values then you should have few dedicated checkboxes, not radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Onclick push the value of radio in array

```js
var arr=[];
$('input').click(function(){
arr.push("."+$(this).val().split('####.###')[1])

console.log(arr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="####.###/resources/videos/7.mp4">Video1
<input type="radio" value="####.###/resources/videos/8.mp4">Video2
<input type="radio" value="####.###/resources/videos/9.mp4">Video3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `change` event listener, that checks if the input got checked or unchecked and would add it or remove it from the list.

```js
var originalVideoList = ["./resources/videos/7.mp4",
  "./resources/videos/1.mp4",
  "./resources/videos/2.mp4",
  "./resources/videos/3.mp4"
];

var videos = document.querySelector("#videos");
var result = document.querySelector("#result");
var template = "<li><label for='{0}'>Video {1}</label><input id='{0}' type='checkbox' onchange='onChange()'/></li>";

var selectedArray = [];

// Set up html
videos.innerHTML = originalVideoList.map(function(video) {
  return template.replace(/\{0\}/g, video).replace(/\{1\}/g, video.split("/").pop());
}).join("");

// triggered on input change
function onChange() {
  selectedArray = toArray(document.querySelectorAll("li>input:checked")).map(function(item) {
    return item.id.replace("####.###", ".");
  });
  result.innerHTML = selectedArray.map(function(video) {
    return "<li>" + video + "</li>";
  }).join("");
}

// Same as [...input]
function toArray(input) {
  var result = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < input.length; index++) result[index] = input[index];
  return result;
}
```

```html
<ul id="videos"></ul>
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

Comment: OP has specifically said a radio button. It works well but for the radio button, you can't de-select the value other clicking its sibling, so it is better to apprise about this in your post.

Comment: @Rohit416 I don't think OP intentionally used radio-buttons, I've added a comment regarding the issue to the question. Will change my answer accordingly depending on OP's response.

Comment: I have asked the OP about this. I think it should have been check boxes.